# Check deleted video when getting comments

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am getting statistics (video/list) and comments (commentThreads/list) for some videos and I would like to know when a video has been deleted but the problem is that no error is thrown for a removed video.

The returned results are empty for a deleted video but I cannot be 100% sure the video was deleted or it is just a matter that the video does not have comments or insights.

Is there a way to get this fixed?

Comment: Can you give an example of a video for which you're trying to get comments?

Comment: Sorry, I meant an example of a deleted video where you can't tell if it's deleted or not (when using the API).

Comment: Sorry, my bad: O7QxDXU9abs

Comment: I've read that if you specify `part=id` for a `videos.list` request and the `items` array is empty, then the video was deleted (or doesn't exist), but I'm not sure how often that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with [id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) = {VIDEOID}

There won't be any video in response if the video is deleted.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, I just wanted to make sure I was doing it properly.

Comment: By the way, it would more than great to know that a video has been removed when getting its comments so that we can save a request per video.